# ffmpeg / ffplay DSLR help

Tags: video, webcam, ffmpeg

I use the following command with ffmpeg to create a virtual webcam in linux 18.04 for my DSLR camera:

```
gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video1
```

The problem is that the video is very slow (it has a lag of around 1 second).

I also have this code with ffplay:

```
gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffplay -framerate 30 -probesize 32 -sync video  -
```

this produces video with much less lag but creates a dedicated window with the video. I would like to direct the video to `/dev/video1`. As far as I can tell ffplay uses ffmpeg. So my question are:

1. how can I change the command of ffmpeg to work with the same settings as ffplay, so that I will have the lower lattency.
2. is it possible to send the ffplay result to /dev/video1 instead of the dedicated window?

Here is the output when I run the first command:

```
blue@blue:~$ gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video1
Capturing preview frames as movie to 'stdout'. Press Ctrl-C to abort.
ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libtesseract --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
[mjpeg @ 0x55b1faaf29c0] Format mjpeg detected only with low score of 25, misdetection possible!
Input #0, mjpeg, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1056x704, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> rawvideo (native))
[swscaler @ 0x55b1fab33b60] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, v4l2, to '/dev/video1':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 1056x704, q=2-31, 223027 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 rawvideo
frame=   49 fps= 24 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:01.96 bitrate=N/A speed=0.965x
frame=   61 fps= 24 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:02.44 bitrate=N/A speed=0.962x
frame=   71 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:02.84 bitrate=N/A speed=0.931x
frame=   82 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:03.28 bitrate=N/A speed=0.921x
```

Comment: Show the complete log from your first command.

Comment: @llogan I posted the output of the first command in my answer.

Comment: Upgrade your ffmpeg ([download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) or [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu)) and try `gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -c copy -f v4l2 /dev/video1`